# Show the first and last labels when tick autoskip is enabled

Tags: chart.js

I want to use the autoSkip option in order to limit the number of labels displayed, but I would like the first and the last labels are always shown.

```
scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          type: 'category',
          ticks: {
            autoSkip": true,
            maxTicksLimit: 10
          }
        }]
      }
```

With the above options the tick is limited to 10, the first label is shown, but the there isn't the last one.
From what I understand, the first label is always printed.
[Here's a chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGeUq.jpg)

I'm using [ng2-charts](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts)  for Angular.
The following are the relevant portions of HTML and js.

```js
public options = { "responsive":true,
          "scales": {
            "xAxes": [{
              "bounds": 'ticks',
              "type": 'category',
              "ticks": {
                "autoSkip": true,
                "maxTicksLimit": 10
              }
            }]
          }
        };

public dataSets: ChartDataSets[] = [{ data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },];

public labels: Label[] = ['01/01/2020', '02/01/2020', '03/01/2020', '04/01/2020', '05/01/2020', '06/01/2020', '07/01/2020'];
```

```html
    <div style="display: block">
      <canvas baseChart
        [chartType]="'bar'"
        [datasets]="dataSets"
        [labels]="labels"
        [options]="options"
        ></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the entire code use currently use for producing your chart. It will make it easier to come up with a viable solution.

Comment: I'm using ng2-chart and I think that the entire code could be misguided.
I think so because my question is  generic and it's about chartjs: Can I show the first and last labels with the autoSkip enabled?
In any case, I've added an example of code.